# Multiple MYSQL Servers on a single windows PC

Tags: mysql, sqlcmd

I have a situation like this,..I have made a installer for my java application which is using `mysql` as the database server.

But the clients machine also will have `mysql` installed and server instance may be there on port 3306.and I need to configure the server password,data locations separately..so that my program can be configured to use them.

I need the `cmd` commands to make this happen.

Any descriptive help?

Thank you.

> EDIT

I've used below

```
[myserver]
basedir = C:/mysql-5.5
port = 3308
enable-named-pipe
socket = mypipe2
```

saved this to a `my-opts1.cnf` file then used the

```
C:\mysql-5.1.55\bin\mysqld --install myserver --defaults-file=C:\my-opts1.cnf
```

the **Service successfully installed.**..but when i start the service using

```
net start myserver
```

then an error occurred. I have questions like what is the password and the user name..what did I missed.

Please help.

Comment: **What have you tried?** If you can't demonstrate even five minutes worth of effort and then start making demands, you're not going about this the right way.

Comment: I have tried .cnf files with different port numbers.but I did not get any working result/

Comment: Still not seeing the command you used.

Comment: That's looking a lot better. Not sure what `net start` is doing here, that may not support running several at the same time. If you're really in a jam, you may want to consider using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and run a bunch of virtual machines.